# route based on context property

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have Route object like this

```
const Routes = (
    <Route>
        <Route path="/g/*" component={Gallery} />
        <Route path="*/cat.jump" render={props => <Gallery {...props} catJump />} />
    </Route>);

export default Routes;
```

i wanted to route when /g/* path is there and context.isSite true to path 
 else path

any idea how i can do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom Route component where you would resolve exact path based on Context. After that, just redirect with `<Redirect to={{ pathname: resolvedPath }}/>` in that custom Route component.